# Could we consider a copy of $l^2(G)$ as a subset of $l^2(G,X)$?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

Suppose that $G$ is a discrete group, and $X$ is a Banach space. Trivially we have a copy of $C_c(G)$ in $C_c(G,X).$ One may choose an element $x$ in $X$, and fix it. Then for each $f$ in $C_c(G)$, we define $f_x$ to be a function from $G$ to $X$ with $f_x(g)=f(g)x$ for all $g$ in $G$. Then $f_x$ is in $C_c(G,X)$ and we may consider a copy of $C_c(G)$ as a subset of  $C_c(G,X)$. Then if we consider  the completion of $C_c(G,X)$ , could we still have a copy of $l^2(G)$ in this completion( I mean in $l^2(G,X)$)?

Comment: Yes, you are right. So, $l^2(G)$  could be considered as a subset of $l^2(G,X)$ without extra condition. Thank you.

Comment: You could define directly $f(\bullet)x\in l^2(G,X)$ for all $f\in l^2(G)$, and this map makes the diagram commute $$\begin{matrix} C_c(G)&\stackrel{\text{yours}}{\longrightarrow} & C_c(G,X)\\ \downarrow\text{std.} &&\downarrow\text{std.}\\ l^2(G)&\stackrel{f\mapsto f(\bullet)x}\longrightarrow& l^2(G,X)\end{matrix}$$